# Tailwind class not applied

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to use Tailwind CSS but it doesn't seem to work. Below code only shows up as a standard **Processing** string and not a button SVG as by their example. What am I doing wrong? Is there some easy way to test if it's actually installed and imported properly?

Thank you!

```
loading() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button type="button" className="bg-rose-600 ..." disabled>
                <svg className="animate-spin h-5 w-5 mr-3 ..." viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                </svg>
                Processing
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Index.css:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Package.json:

```
{


"name": "myName",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.1.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "postcss": "^7.0.35",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening the developer tools and seeing if the styles are being applied from there?

Tailwind css is also not in the package.json file, so I'm assuming that you don't have it installed.

Try following the guide at https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation, they explain how to get it set up from there.

Comment: I did follow it and it's in the devDependencies. Where should it be other than that?

Comment: Went through the setup again and all my configs and files looks like they should

Comment: Are you importing index.css in the file that you're trying to get it working in? Alternatively, you could just try importing tailwind into that file if you don't care about writing your own styles if you aren't already.